# Псевдокласс hover работает с svg, а focus нет

Tags: html, css, css-animation

Не могу понять, почему не работает `:focus` при прохождении по элементам с помощью клавиши tab. Hover без каких либо проблем заработал.

```css
.f-social-item a svg:hover,
    .f-social-item a svg:focus{
        fill:#fff;
        outline: none;
    }
```

```html
<section class="footer-social-media">
                <h2>Social media</h2>
                <ul class="f-social-list">
                    <li class="f-social-item">
                        <a href="https://facebook.com">
                            <svg height="25px" viewBox="-172 -21 682 682.66669" width="25px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="m221.796875 640h-162.503906v-226.246094h-69.042969v-150.003906h69.042969v-100.628906c0-89.949219 73.175781-163.121094 163.117187-163.121094h105.9375v162.507812h-80.410156c-14.410156 0-26.140625 11.726563-26.140625 26.132813v75.105469h69.042969v150.007812h-69.042969zm0 0"/>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <!--<li class="f-social-item"><a href="https://facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>-->
                    <li class="f-social-item">
                        <a href="https://twitter.com">
                            <svg height="25px" viewBox="-21 -49 682.66669 682" width="25px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="m222.40625 583.089844c-35.859375 0-70.105469-6.722656-102.0625-20.074219-32.472656-13.5625-61.5625-33.75-84.140625-58.375l-35.890625-39.152344 52.503906 8.019531c49.167969 7.511719 80.695313 2.496094 99.824219-4.277343-15.339844-7.253907-34.078125-17.675781-53.0625-32.039063-59.25-44.847656-92.722656-106.898437-96.789063-179.4375l-2.789062-49.773437 22.476562 23c-3.644531-24.023438-4.277343-54.671875 3.101563-91.125l11.707031-57.835938 14.117188 32.105469c3.277344-24.859375 11.503906-53.242188 30.214844-80.363281l24.390624-35.34375 9.269532 41.925781c10.367187 46.875 27.203125 85.820312 50.042968 115.753906 17.902344 23.457032 39.585938 41.523438 64.449219 53.699219 23.230469 11.378906 45.136719 15.527344 60.382813 16.945313-.753906-5.996094-1.128906-12.050782-1.128906-18.140626 0-80.027343 65.113281-145.140624 145.140624-145.140624 33.3125 0 65.855469 11.570312 91.632813 32.585937 22.503906 18.339844 39.050781 43.15625 47.367187 70.722656l66.835938 20.859375-60.699219 49.386719v8.0625c0 88.757813-35.207031 171.863281-99.148437 234.007813-61.839844 60.105468-145.949219 96.777343-236.828125 103.257812-7.03125.496094-14.007813.746094-20.917969.746094zm0 0"/>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="f-social-item">
                        <a href="https://instagram.com">
                            <svg height="25px" viewBox="-21 -21 682.66669 682.66669" width="25px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="m0 132.976562v374.046876c0 73.441406 59.535156 132.976562 132.976562 132.976562h374.046876c73.441406 0 132.976562-59.535156 132.976562-132.976562v-374.046876c0-73.441406-59.535156-132.976562-132.976562-132.976562h-374.046876c-73.441406 0-132.976562 59.535156-132.976562 132.976562zm387.792969 368.359376c-157.855469 54.464843-303.59375-91.273438-249.128907-249.128907 18.351563-53.203125 60.335938-95.191406 113.539063-113.542969 157.859375-54.464843 303.597656 91.273438 249.132813 249.132813-18.351563 53.203125-60.335938 95.1875-113.542969 113.539063zm154.28125-374.859376c-2.511719 13.152344-13.394531 20.804688-24.652344 20.804688-6.851563 0-13.835937-2.828125-19.183594-8.964844-.472656-.542968-.914062-1.125-1.304687-1.730468-5.519532-8.4375-5.691406-18.460938-1-26.589844 3.320312-5.753906 8.679687-9.863282 15.097656-11.582032 6.410156-1.726562 13.113281-.839843 18.859375 2.484376 8.132813 4.6875 12.992187 13.457031 12.4375 23.511718-.039063.6875-.121094 1.386719-.253906 2.066406zm0 0"/><path d="m320 164.523438c-85.734375 0-155.476562 69.742187-155.476562 155.476562s69.742187 155.476562 155.476562 155.476562 155.476562-69.742187 155.476562-155.476562-69.742187-155.476562-155.476562-155.476562zm0 0"/>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                    <li class="f-social-item">
                        <a href="https://google.com">
                            <svg height="25px" viewBox="-21 -44 682.66669 682" width="25px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="m257.21875 592.191406c-141.832031 0-257.21875-115.382812-257.21875-257.214844 0-141.828124 115.386719-257.21875 257.21875-257.21875 45.804688 0 90.785156 12.199219 130.078125 35.273438l15.203125 8.933594-56.210938 110.179687-17.339843-10.957031c-21.429688-13.546875-46.234375-20.703125-71.730469-20.703125-74.164062 0-134.492188 60.332031-134.492188 134.492187 0 74.164063 60.328126 134.496094 134.492188 134.496094 28.019531 0 55.511719-8.65625 77.410156-24.378906 14.320313-10.277344 25.882813-23.351562 33.867188-38.027344l-117.515625-.003906v-117.351562h260.105469l1.78125 16.730468c1.007812 9.5 1.566406 19.632813 1.566406 28.535156 0 141.832032-115.386719 257.214844-257.214844 257.214844zm0 0"/><path d="m585.96875 207.035156h-100.222656v-54.03125h-54.03125v-100.21875h54.03125v-54.035156h100.222656v54.035156h54.03125v100.21875h-54.03125zm0 0"/>
                            </svg>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </section>
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Чтобы работал псевдо класс `:focus` элемент должен быть `input`, `button`, `textarea`... (т.е. быть интерактивным изначально) или иметь атрибут `tabindex`

```css
.f-social-item a svg:hover {
  fill: blue;
  outline: none;
}

.f-social-item a svg:focus {
  fill: red;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="footer-social-media">
  <h2>Social media</h2>
  <ul class="f-social-list">
    <li class="f-social-item">
      <a href="https://facebook.com">
        <svg tabindex=0 height="25px" viewBox="-172 -21 682 682.66669" width="25px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="m221.796875 640h-162.503906v-226.246094h-69.042969v-150.003906h69.042969v-100.628906c0-89.949219 73.175781-163.121094 163.117187-163.121094h105.9375v162.507812h-80.410156c-14.410156 0-26.140625 11.726563-26.140625 26.132813v75.105469h69.042969v150.007812h-69.042969zm0 0"/>
                            </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <!--<li class="f-social-item"><a href="https://facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>-->
    <li class="f-social-item">
      <a href="https://twitter.com">
        <svg tabindex=0 height="25px" viewBox="-21 -49 682.66669 682" width="25px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="m222.40625 583.089844c-35.859375 0-70.105469-6.722656-102.0625-20.074219-32.472656-13.5625-61.5625-33.75-84.140625-58.375l-35.890625-39.152344 52.503906 8.019531c49.167969 7.511719 80.695313 2.496094 99.824219-4.277343-15.339844-7.253907-34.078125-17.675781-53.0625-32.039063-59.25-44.847656-92.722656-106.898437-96.789063-179.4375l-2.789062-49.773437 22.476562 23c-3.644531-24.023438-4.277343-54.671875 3.101563-91.125l11.707031-57.835938 14.117188 32.105469c3.277344-24.859375 11.503906-53.242188 30.214844-80.363281l24.390624-35.34375 9.269532 41.925781c10.367187 46.875 27.203125 85.820312 50.042968 115.753906 17.902344 23.457032 39.585938 41.523438 64.449219 53.699219 23.230469 11.378906 45.136719 15.527344 60.382813 16.945313-.753906-5.996094-1.128906-12.050782-1.128906-18.140626 0-80.027343 65.113281-145.140624 145.140624-145.140624 33.3125 0 65.855469 11.570312 91.632813 32.585937 22.503906 18.339844 39.050781 43.15625 47.367187 70.722656l66.835938 20.859375-60.699219 49.386719v8.0625c0 88.757813-35.207031 171.863281-99.148437 234.007813-61.839844 60.105468-145.949219 96.777343-236.828125 103.257812-7.03125.496094-14.007813.746094-20.917969.746094zm0 0"/>
                            </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="f-social-item">
      <a href="https://instagram.com">
        <svg tabindex=0 height="25px" viewBox="-21 -21 682.66669 682.66669" width="25px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="m0 132.976562v374.046876c0 73.441406 59.535156 132.976562 132.976562 132.976562h374.046876c73.441406 0 132.976562-59.535156 132.976562-132.976562v-374.046876c0-73.441406-59.535156-132.976562-132.976562-132.976562h-374.046876c-73.441406 0-132.976562 59.535156-132.976562 132.976562zm387.792969 368.359376c-157.855469 54.464843-303.59375-91.273438-249.128907-249.128907 18.351563-53.203125 60.335938-95.191406 113.539063-113.542969 157.859375-54.464843 303.597656 91.273438 249.132813 249.132813-18.351563 53.203125-60.335938 95.1875-113.542969 113.539063zm154.28125-374.859376c-2.511719 13.152344-13.394531 20.804688-24.652344 20.804688-6.851563 0-13.835937-2.828125-19.183594-8.964844-.472656-.542968-.914062-1.125-1.304687-1.730468-5.519532-8.4375-5.691406-18.460938-1-26.589844 3.320312-5.753906 8.679687-9.863282 15.097656-11.582032 6.410156-1.726562 13.113281-.839843 18.859375 2.484376 8.132813 4.6875 12.992187 13.457031 12.4375 23.511718-.039063.6875-.121094 1.386719-.253906 2.066406zm0 0"/><path d="m320 164.523438c-85.734375 0-155.476562 69.742187-155.476562 155.476562s69.742187 155.476562 155.476562 155.476562 155.476562-69.742187 155.476562-155.476562-69.742187-155.476562-155.476562-155.476562zm0 0"/>
                            </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="f-social-item">
      <a href="https://google.com">
        <svg tabindex=0 height="25px" viewBox="-21 -44 682.66669 682" width="25px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="m257.21875 592.191406c-141.832031 0-257.21875-115.382812-257.21875-257.214844 0-141.828124 115.386719-257.21875 257.21875-257.21875 45.804688 0 90.785156 12.199219 130.078125 35.273438l15.203125 8.933594-56.210938 110.179687-17.339843-10.957031c-21.429688-13.546875-46.234375-20.703125-71.730469-20.703125-74.164062 0-134.492188 60.332031-134.492188 134.492187 0 74.164063 60.328126 134.496094 134.492188 134.496094 28.019531 0 55.511719-8.65625 77.410156-24.378906 14.320313-10.277344 25.882813-23.351562 33.867188-38.027344l-117.515625-.003906v-117.351562h260.105469l1.78125 16.730468c1.007812 9.5 1.566406 19.632813 1.566406 28.535156 0 141.832032-115.386719 257.214844-257.214844 257.214844zm0 0"/><path d="m585.96875 207.035156h-100.222656v-54.03125h-54.03125v-100.21875h54.03125v-54.035156h100.222656v54.035156h54.03125v100.21875h-54.03125zm0 0"/>
                            </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

---

или если Вы используете ссылки, то на них и нужно вешать псевдо класс:

```css
.f-social-item a:hover svg,
.f-social-item a:focus svg {
  fill: red;
  outline: none;
}
```

```html
<section class="footer-social-media">
  <h2>Social media</h2>
  <ul class="f-social-list">
    <li class="f-social-item">
      <a href="https://facebook.com">
        <svg height="25px" viewBox="-172 -21 682 682.66669" width="25px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="m221.796875 640h-162.503906v-226.246094h-69.042969v-150.003906h69.042969v-100.628906c0-89.949219 73.175781-163.121094 163.117187-163.121094h105.9375v162.507812h-80.410156c-14.410156 0-26.140625 11.726563-26.140625 26.132813v75.105469h69.042969v150.007812h-69.042969zm0 0"/>
                            </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <!--<li class="f-social-item"><a href="https://facebook.com">Facebook</a></li>-->
    <li class="f-social-item">
      <a href="https://twitter.com">
        <svg height="25px" viewBox="-21 -49 682.66669 682" width="25px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="m222.40625 583.089844c-35.859375 0-70.105469-6.722656-102.0625-20.074219-32.472656-13.5625-61.5625-33.75-84.140625-58.375l-35.890625-39.152344 52.503906 8.019531c49.167969 7.511719 80.695313 2.496094 99.824219-4.277343-15.339844-7.253907-34.078125-17.675781-53.0625-32.039063-59.25-44.847656-92.722656-106.898437-96.789063-179.4375l-2.789062-49.773437 22.476562 23c-3.644531-24.023438-4.277343-54.671875 3.101563-91.125l11.707031-57.835938 14.117188 32.105469c3.277344-24.859375 11.503906-53.242188 30.214844-80.363281l24.390624-35.34375 9.269532 41.925781c10.367187 46.875 27.203125 85.820312 50.042968 115.753906 17.902344 23.457032 39.585938 41.523438 64.449219 53.699219 23.230469 11.378906 45.136719 15.527344 60.382813 16.945313-.753906-5.996094-1.128906-12.050782-1.128906-18.140626 0-80.027343 65.113281-145.140624 145.140624-145.140624 33.3125 0 65.855469 11.570312 91.632813 32.585937 22.503906 18.339844 39.050781 43.15625 47.367187 70.722656l66.835938 20.859375-60.699219 49.386719v8.0625c0 88.757813-35.207031 171.863281-99.148437 234.007813-61.839844 60.105468-145.949219 96.777343-236.828125 103.257812-7.03125.496094-14.007813.746094-20.917969.746094zm0 0"/>
                            </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="f-social-item">
      <a href="https://instagram.com">
        <svg height="25px" viewBox="-21 -21 682.66669 682.66669" width="25px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                            <path d="m0 132.976562v374.046876c0 73.441406 59.535156 132.976562 132.976562 132.976562h374.046876c73.441406 0 132.976562-59.535156 132.976562-132.976562v-374.046876c0-73.441406-59.535156-132.976562-132.976562-132.976562h-374.046876c-73.441406 0-132.976562 59.535156-132.976562 132.976562zm387.792969 368.359376c-157.855469 54.464843-303.59375-91.273438-249.128907-249.128907 18.351563-53.203125 60.335938-95.191406 113.539063-113.542969 157.859375-54.464843 303.597656 91.273438 249.132813 249.132813-18.351563 53.203125-60.335938 95.1875-113.542969 113.539063zm154.28125-374.859376c-2.511719 13.152344-13.394531 20.804688-24.652344 20.804688-6.851563 0-13.835937-2.828125-19.183594-8.964844-.472656-.542968-.914062-1.125-1.304687-1.730468-5.519532-8.4375-5.691406-18.460938-1-26.589844 3.320312-5.753906 8.679687-9.863282 15.097656-11.582032 6.410156-1.726562 13.113281-.839843 18.859375 2.484376 8.132813 4.6875 12.992187 13.457031 12.4375 23.511718-.039063.6875-.121094 1.386719-.253906 2.066406zm0 0"/><path d="m320 164.523438c-85.734375 0-155.476562 69.742187-155.476562 155.476562s69.742187 155.476562 155.476562 155.476562 155.476562-69.742187 155.476562-155.476562-69.742187-155.476562-155.476562-155.476562zm0 0"/>
                            </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
    <li class="f-social-item">
      <a href="https://google.com">
        <svg height="25px" viewBox="-21 -44 682.66669 682" width="25px" xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg">
                                <path d="m257.21875 592.191406c-141.832031 0-257.21875-115.382812-257.21875-257.214844 0-141.828124 115.386719-257.21875 257.21875-257.21875 45.804688 0 90.785156 12.199219 130.078125 35.273438l15.203125 8.933594-56.210938 110.179687-17.339843-10.957031c-21.429688-13.546875-46.234375-20.703125-71.730469-20.703125-74.164062 0-134.492188 60.332031-134.492188 134.492187 0 74.164063 60.328126 134.496094 134.492188 134.496094 28.019531 0 55.511719-8.65625 77.410156-24.378906 14.320313-10.277344 25.882813-23.351562 33.867188-38.027344l-117.515625-.003906v-117.351562h260.105469l1.78125 16.730468c1.007812 9.5 1.566406 19.632813 1.566406 28.535156 0 141.832032-115.386719 257.214844-257.214844 257.214844zm0 0"/><path d="m585.96875 207.035156h-100.222656v-54.03125h-54.03125v-100.21875h54.03125v-54.035156h100.222656v54.035156h54.03125v100.21875h-54.03125zm0 0"/>
                            </svg>
      </a>
    </li>
  </ul>
</section>
```

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь все стало ясно!

Comment: В firefox все работает. Единственная проблема это то, что при наличии tabindex проход tab' ом по странице начинается с футера.

Comment: @DenysSkotarenko посмотрите второй сниппет

Comment: Спасибо! Теперь работает. Очень благодарен!